# Plot data for each row within a single command

Tags: r, plot, row

I'm an R newbie and need help with the following.

I have the following data

```
# Simulate matrix of integers 
set.seed(1) 
df <- matrix(sample.int(5, size = 3*5, replace = TRUE), nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
print(df)
df <- tbl_df(df)  # tabulate as dataframe 
df <- rbind(df, c(3,5,4,1,4)) 
print(df)
```

Within a single command, I need to plot the data for each row, so that y-axis: data in each row (in my case these are values from 1 to 5); x-axis: values 1,2,3,4,5 that refer to each column. So effectively, for each row, I am trying to plot how row values change for every single column.

I have tried the following, which works but has two problems which I need to resolve. First, this only plots 1 row at a time. Not an efficient way of doing things especially if there are many rows. Second, I could not find a way to refer to the x-axis as the number of columns, so I resorted to simply counting the number of columns (i.e. 5) and put a c(1:5) vector to represent a number of columns. I also tried to put ncol(df) to represent x-axis but that returns an error saying that variables have different length. Indeed when requesting ncol(df) it return number 5, which is the number of columns but it does not do what I wanted it to, i.e. to represent number of columns sequentially 1,2,3,4,5.

```
 plot(c(1:5),df[1,], type = "b", pch=19,
 col = "blue", xlab = "number of columns", ylab = "response format")
```

Thank you, your help is much appreciated

Comment: A base R one-liner: `matplot(t(df), type = "l", pch = 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(row_number = as.factor(row_number())) %>%
  gather(columns, responses, V1:V5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = columns, y = responses, group = row_number, color = row_number)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]

What this does:

- Creates an id for each row (`row_number`);
- Transforms the data frame into a long format with 1 column for `columns`, and another for `responses`;
- Plots everything on 1 chart where each color represents one row.

You could also slightly change the plot so that each line (row) has its own chart by adding `facet_wrap`, e.g.:

```
df %>%
  mutate(row_number = as.factor(row_number())) %>%
  gather(columns, responses, V1:V5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = columns, y = responses, group = row_number, color = row_number)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ row_number)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply! This is exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you once more and have a good day